# wordpress Tiny mce button to display a custom html div

Tags: button, tinymce, wordpress

iam trying to add a tiny mce button to display a template like this

```
<div class ="template1">
<img src="" />
<span>
<b>name:[cf]name[/cf] </b>
<span>
</div>
```

name of the button temp1, if i click it, should add the above code in the text editor, `[cf]name[/cf]` is the short code to display name from the value.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.addButton

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you will need. Addiationally you will need to choose an icon and to add the button name to your button config in your tinymce init (`theme_advanced_buttons1: 'your_button_name, save, table,...'`).

```
  // Register example button
  ed.addButton('example', {
     title : 'name:[cf]name[/cf]',
     image : '../jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/example/img/example.gif',
     onclick : function() {
        //ed.windowManager.alert('Hello world!! Selection: ' + ed.selection.getContent({format : 'text'}));
        var content = '<div class ="template1"><img src="" /><span><b>name:[cf]name[/cf] </b><span></div>';
        ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, content);
     }
  });
```

Comment: how to add this in wordpress functions.php?